# java hashmap with a class value

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to store a `TDSContent` into a hashmap specifying a `String` key. I need to do something like this.

```
public class Target {
    public Target() {
        final int a = 0x64c896;
        final int b = 0xc050be;
        final int c = 0xffc896;

        TDS = new HashMap<String, TDSContent>();

        TDSContent contentMA = new TDSContent(a, b, c, 10);
        TDSContent contentMB = new TDSContent(a, c, b, 10);
        TDSContent contentMC = new TDSContent(b, a, c, 10);
        TDSContent contentMD = new TDSContent(c, b, a, 10);
        TDSContent contentME = new TDSContent(c, a, b, 10);
        TDSContent contentMF = new TDSContent(b, c, a, 10);
        ... // and so on...

        TDS.put("Marker A", contentMA);
        TDS.put("Marker B", contentMB);
        TDS.put("Marker C", contentMC);
        TDS.put("Marker D", contentMD);
        TDS.put("Marker E", contentME);
        TDS.put("Marker F", contentMF);
            ... // and so on...
    }

    public int getCL(String key) {
        TDSContent tdc = TDS.get(key);

        if(tdc.equals(contentMA)) {
            return contentMA.getValue();
        } else if(tdc.equals(contentMB)) {
            return contentMB.getValue();
        } else if(tdc.equals(contentMC)) {
            return contentMC.getValue();
        } else if(tdc.equals(contentMD)) {
            return contentMD.getValue();
        } else if(tdc.equals(contentME)) {
            return contentME.getValue();
        } else if(tdc.equals(contentMF)) {
            return contentMF.getValue();
        } ...// and so on...

             else {
            return contentMD.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, it will take so much hard work to manually create an object of class `TDSContent`.

Can I do something like this ...:

```
public class Target {
    public Target() {
        final int a = 0x64c896;
        final int b = 0xc050be;
        final int c = 0xffc896;

        TDS = new HashMap<String, TDSContent>();

           // form: new TDSContent(CL, CM, CR, D);
        TDS.put("Marker A", new TDSContent(a, b, c, 10));
        TDS.put("Marker B", new TDSContent(a, c, b, 10));
                ... // and so on..
    }

    public int getCL(String key) {
           // this method gets the first parameter of the TDSContent
           // constructor (see comment above).
        return TDS.get(key).getValue();
    }

    public int getCM(String key) {
    ... // similar to getCL but returns the second parameter of the TDSContent
        // constructor (see comment above)
```

... on `getCL()` and get and the instantiated[?] value of TDSContent?

Specifically, if I have a call on something like:

```
Target target = new Target();
int x1 = target.getCL("Marker A"); // I should get 0x64c896 here
int x2 = target.getCM("Marker A"); // I should get 0xc050be here
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, just match the `getXXX()` method you call on the `TDSContent` object in the map to the accessor. This assumes you have accessors on `TDSContent` for each constructor argument.

```
public int getCL(String key) {
    return TDS.get(key).getCL();
}

public int getCM(String key) {
    return TDS.get(key).getCM();
}

public int getCR(String key) {
    return TDS.get(key).getCR();
}

public int getD(String key) {
    return TDS.get(key).getD();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a `TDSContent` whether or not you assign it to a variable as an intermediate step.

I don't really understand the purpose behind the first implementation of `getCL`, it seems like it *completely* defeats the purpose of having a map in the first place. (I don't see where `TDS` is declared, only assigned.)

I might go a tad bit further and create some handy utility methods to make things even shorter, though, if there's a "lot" of them.

```
putTds("Marker B", tds(a, c, b, 10));
```

The idea of creating `getCL` and `getCM` helper methods is a good one, and can *greatly* increase program readability.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a better way of implementing the ones above?

Comment: @NeigylNoval See David's answer; I misunderstood a portion of the question.